# Bar chart almost complete, but data isnt updating above when mover is moved horizontally

Tags: d3.js, svg, charts, bar-chart

I have made a grouped bar chart, but data isnt updating above when the below mover is moved, i dont know how to change the transform of .bar , how to use exit and remove here, as it is a grouped bar chart.
the new rects are going inside the groups and its getting messy.

This is my grouped bar chart

```
var counter = 0;
      
var dataset = [];

var found = 0;

var moverToLast = 0;

var moverToFirst = 0;

var of;

var displayFlag=0;

var selectBar;

var firstSubBarLength;



function buildBar(selectBar){
    displayFlag = 1;
    $('#barChart').text('');

    dataset = [{"user_id":"AAAA0001","my_count":1,"sale_count":1,"lead_count":0}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0002","my_count":6,"sale_count":5,"lead_count":2}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0003","my_count":13,"sale_count":6,"lead_count":3}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0004","my_count":11,"sale_count":12,"lead_count":4}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0005","my_count":5,"sale_count":6,"lead_count":5}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0006","my_count":6,"sale_count":10,"lead_count":6}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0007","my_count":13,"sale_count":2,"lead_count":7}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0008","my_count":11,"sale_count":0,"lead_count":8}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0009","my_count":7,"sale_count":11,"lead_count":9}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0010","my_count":1,"sale_count":7,"lead_count":10}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0011","my_count":4,"sale_count":4,"lead_count":11}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0012","my_count":15,"sale_count":8,"lead_count":12}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0013","my_count":1,"sale_count":15,"lead_count":13}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0014","my_count":8,"sale_count":1,"lead_count":14}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0015","my_count":9,"sale_count":8,"lead_count":15}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0016","my_count":4,"sale_count":11,"lead_count":16}
,{"user_id":"AAAA0017","my_count":18,"sale_count":4,"lead_count":17}
,{"user_id":"AAAA1234","my_count":6,"sale_count":12,"lead_count":1}
,{"user_id":"ABHI1245","my_count":10,"sale_count":7,"lead_count":1}
,{"user_id":"ABHI2188","my_count":1,"sale_count":4,"lead_count":1}
,{"user_id":"BBBB1234","my_count":1,"sale_count":3,"lead_count":1}
,{"user_id":"DDDD1235","my_count":7,"sale_count":10,"lead_count":1}
,{"user_id":"DEEP1234","my_count":1,"sale_count":6,"lead_count":1}
,{"user_id":"EEEE2188","my_count":1,"sale_count":5,"lead_count":1}
,{"user_id":"QWER1234","my_count":10,"sale_count":5,"lead_count":1}
,{"user_id":"ROHI1234","my_count":6,"sale_count":12,"lead_count":1}];    
    


    var barTooltip = d3.select("#barChart").append("div")   
      .attr("class", "tooltip")               
      .style("opacity", 0);

var formatRatio = d3.format("%");            

    
 
                    
var margin =  {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40};
var marginOverview = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40};
var selectorHeight = 40;
var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom - selectorHeight;
var heightOverview = 80 - marginOverview.top - marginOverview.bottom;
       
var maxLength = d3.max(dataset.map(function(d){ return d.user_id.length}))
var barWidth = maxLength * 7;
console.log("barWidth "+barWidth);
var numBars = Math.round(width/barWidth);
console.log("numBars "+numBars);
console.log("width"+width);
var isScrollDisplayed = barWidth * dataset.length > width;

var user_id = function(d) { return d.user_id; };
var my_count = function(d) { return d.my_count; };
var sale_count = function(d) { return d.sale_count; };
var lead_count = function(d) { return d.lead_count; };
var valueObject = function(d) { return [{name:"my_count", value:my_count(d)},{name:"sale_count", value: sale_count(d)}, {name: "lead_count", value: lead_count(d)}]; };

var val = $('#userId').val();
var colorIndex = 0;
       
 for(var i = 0;i<dataset.length;i++){
        console.log(dataset[i].user_id);
        if(dataset[i].user_id==val){
            found = i-(numBars-5);
            break;
        }
    }

    colorIndex = found;

    var dint = dataset.length - (numBars/2);
    console.log(dint + " dataaa");

    if(found<0){
        found=0;
    }else if(found>(dint-numBars)){
        found = dataset.length-8;
        console.log("in found")
    }
    
    if(selectBar==0){
        found=0;
    }

    console.log("found"+found);

console.log(isScrollDisplayed)

 newData = dataset.slice(found);
 console.log(newData);
  
var xscale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(newData.slice(0,numBars).map(function (d) { return d.user_id; }))
                .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["my_count","sale_count","lead_count"])
    .rangeRoundBands([0, xscale.rangeBand()]);                

var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([0, d3.max(dataset.map(my_count))])
              .nice()
              .range([height, 0]);
  
var xAxis  = d3.svg.axis().scale(xscale).orient("bottom");
var yAxis  = d3.svg.axis().scale(yscale).orient("left").tickSize(-width, 0, 0).tickFormat(d3.format("s"))
        .ticks(10);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["my_count","sale_count","lead_count"])
  .range(["#31a354","#3182bd","#e6550d"]);                                       

    // var minProfit = d3.min(data, function(d){ return d.lead_count; });
 // var maxProfit = d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.lead_count; });
 
 // var color = d3.scale.quantize()
 //  .domain([minProfit, maxProfit])       
 //  .range(['rgb(165,15,21)','rgb(222,45,38)','rgb(251,106,74)','rgb(252,146,114)','rgb(252,187,161)','rgb(254,229,217)','rgb(150, 106, 106)','rgb(64,64,64)']);
                 
  
var svg = d3.select("#barChart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + selectorHeight);
  
var diagram = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  
diagram.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis x-axis")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
       .call(xAxis);
  
diagram.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis y-axis")
       .call(yAxis);
  
var bars = diagram.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(newData.slice(0,numBars))
    .enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xscale(user_id(d)) + ",0)"; });
;
  
bars.selectAll("rect")
    .data(valueObject)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function (d) { return yscale(0); })
    .attr("height", 0)
    .transition().duration(2000)
    .ease("cubic")
    .attr("y", function (d) { return yscale(d.value) })
    .attr("height", function (d) { return height - yscale(d.value); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
    ;

            

// d3.selectAll("rect").style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.lead_count); }).on("mouseover", function(d) {      

// barTooltip.transition()        
//     .duration(500)      
//     .style("opacity", .9);      

// var tip = "<strong>UserID:</strong> " + d.user_id + "<br/>";
// var tip = tip+"<strong>Leads:</strong> " + d.lead_count+ "<br/>";

//  lead_count = d.lead_count;

// barTooltip.html(tip)  
//     .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
//     .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
// })                  
// .on("mouseout", function(d) {       

// barTooltip.transition()        
//     .duration(500)      
//     .style("opacity", 0);   
// }); 


// if(selectBar==1){
//     d3.selectAll("rect").classed("disable",function(d){if(d.user_id!=val){return true}else{return false}}).style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.lead_count);
//     d3.selectAll(".mover").classed("disable",true)    
// });}



  
if (isScrollDisplayed)
{
  var xOverview = d3.scale.ordinal()
                  .domain(dataset.map(user_id))
                  .rangeBands([0, width], .2);

  var xOverview1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(["my_count","sale_count","lead_count"])
            .rangeRoundBands([0, xOverview.rangeBand()]);  

  yOverview = d3.scale.linear().range([heightOverview, 0]);
  yOverview.domain(yscale.domain());

  var subBars = diagram.selectAll('.sub')
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class","sub")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xOverview(user_id(d)) + ",0)"; })
        .classed("selectedSubBar",function(d,i){if(d.user_id==val && i>8 && i<dataset.length-8){return true}else{return false;}})
        .classed("lastSubBar",function(d,i){if(i==dataset.length-1){return true}else{return false;}})
        .classed("firstSubBar",function(d,i){if(i==0){return true}else{return false;}}) 
        ;
    
    
    subBars.selectAll("rect")
        .data(valueObject)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .classed('subBar', true)                   
        .attr("x", function(d) {return xOverview1(d.name);})
        .attr("width", function(d) {return xOverview1.rangeBand()})
        .attr("y", function (d) { return height + heightOverview + yOverview(0); })
        .attr("height", 0)
        .transition().duration(1500)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
        return height + heightOverview + yOverview(d.value)
    })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
        return heightOverview - yOverview(d.value);
    })


  var displayed = d3.scale.quantize()
              .domain([0, width])
              .range(d3.range(dataset.length));

  diagram.append("rect")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
    .attr("class", "mover")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", selectorHeight)
    .attr("width", Math.round(parseFloat(numBars * width)/dataset.length))
    .attr("pointer-events", "all")
    .attr("cursor", "ew-resize")
    .call(d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", display));

    console.log("float  " + Math.round(parseFloat(numBars * width)/dataset.length)/2);

        var rectWidth = $('.sub').width();

        for(var checker = 0; checker < dataset.length; checker++){
            if(dataset[checker].user_id==val){
                if(checker>dataset.length-9){
                    moverToLast = 1;
                    moverToFirst = 0;
                }else if(checker<8){
                    moverToLast = 0;
                    moverToFirst = 1;
                }else{
                    moverToFirst = 0;
                    moverToLast = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        console.log("moverToLast",moverToLast);

        firstSubBarLength = $('.firstSubBar').offset().left - 8;

        console.log("moverToFirst "+moverToFirst);

        if(moverToLast == 1){
            console.log(rectWidth + " rectWidth");
            console.log($('.lastSubBar').offset().left + " $('.lastSubBar').offset().left");
            of = Math.round($('.lastSubBar').offset().left + rectWidth - (parseFloat(numBars * width)/dataset.length)) - firstSubBarLength;
        }else if(moverToFirst == 1){
            of = 0;
        }else{
            of = Math.round($('.selectedSubBar').offset().left - firstSubBarLength - (parseFloat(numBars * width)/dataset.length/2)) + rectWidth;
        }      

    console.log("of ",of) ;        

    if(selectBar==1){
        d3.selectAll('.mover').attr("x",of);
    }else{
        d3.selectAll(".sub").classed("selectedSubBar",false);
    } 
    
                       

}
function display () {

    d3.selectAll(".sub").classed("selectedSubBar",false);

    selectBar=0;
    if(counter==0){
        buildBar(0);
        counter = 1;
    }

    $("#userId").val($("#userId option:first").val());
    console.log("this is lead count "+lead_count);
    d3.selectAll(".bar").classed("disable",false);
    var x = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr("x")),
        nx = x + d3.event.dx,
        w = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr("width")),
        f, nf, new_data, rects,rects1;

        console.log("display x :" + x);
        console.log("this is nx "+nx);

    if ( nx < 0 || nx + w > width ) return;

    d3.select(this).attr("x", nx);

    f = displayed(x);
    nf = displayed(nx+1);

    if ( f === nf ) return;


    new_data = dataset.slice(nf, nf + numBars);
    for(i=0;i<new_data.length;i++){
        console.log("new data " + new_data[i].user_id);
    }
    

    xscale.domain(new_data.map(user_id));
    diagram.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);

     rects = diagram.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(new_data);

    rects
    .enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xscale(user_id(d)) + ",0)"; });
;

var rects1 = rects.selectAll("rect")
    .data(valueObject);

    rects1
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function (d) { return yscale(0); })
    .attr("height", 0)
    .transition().duration(2000)
    .ease("cubic")
    .attr("y", function (d) { return yscale(d.value) })
    .attr("height", function (d) { return height - yscale(d.value); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
    ;

    rects.exit().remove();
    rects1.exit().remove();




};


    

}
.subBar { 
  fill: gray;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.axis path,
.y-axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill: steelblue;
  fill-opacity: .25;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

  rect.mover {
            stroke: red;
            stroke-opacity: .1;
            fill: lightSteelBlue ;
            fill-opacity: .5;
        }

    .disable{
        fill: #c0c0c0 !important;
    }  

    .y-axis line{
                stroke: lightgray;
                stroke-opacity: 0.7;
                shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <select name = "userId" id="userId" href = "javascript:void(0);" onchange="buildBar(1)">
            <option selected disabled>Select User ID</option>
            <option value="AAAA0009">AAAA0009</option>
            <option value="AAAA0010">AAAA0010</option>
            <option value="AAAA0011">AAAA0011</option>
            <option value="AAAA0003">AAAA0003</option>
            <option value="AAAA0002">AAAA0002</option>
            <option value="AAAA0004">AAAA0004</option>
            <option value="AAAA0006">AAAA0006</option>
            <option value="AAAA0007">AAAA0007</option>
            <option value="AAAA0008">AAAA0008</option>
            <option value="AAAA0005">AAAA0005</option>
            <option value="AAAA0001">AAAA0001</option>
            <option value="AAAA0000">AAAA0000</option>
            <option value="clay">clay</option>
            <option value="rohi1234">rohi1234</option>
            <option value="rohi1236">rohi1236</option>
            <option value="AAAA0012">AAAA0012</option>
            <option value="AAAA0013">AAAA0013</option>
            <option value="AAAA0014">AAAA0014</option>
            <option value="AAAA0015">AAAA0015</option>
            <option value="AAAA0016">AAAA0016</option>
            <option value="AAAA0017">AAAA0017</option>
            <option value="daca2111">daca2111</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="topChart" style=" width: 800px;">
           <!-- <div id="barChartLegend"></div> -->
           <svg id="barChartLegend"></svg> 
            <div id="barChart" href = "javascript:void(0);" onclick="buildBar(0)"></div>
        </div>
```

I started with a simple bar chart, it worked fine.

Comment: the problem is in the display function, as it gets called when the mover is dragged

Comment: the x axis are changing just the bars arent getting displayed